# Get JSON data to HTML file

Tags: html, json

whats up? I'm new to web developer and a start make a database for mangas! So, to start i create a php file with a card grid and i need a json file with a manga database to import to card like:

- "image"
- "name"
- "category"
- "downlaod_link"

**!This is one simple card!**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
      <div class="card h-100">
        <a href=" |manga_link| "><img class="card-img-top" src=" |manga_img_src| "></a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">
            <a href="#"> |manga_title| </a>
          </h4>
          <p class="card-text"> |manga_category| </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**!And this is my json file! I place just the necessary line because is a big file!**

```
[
    {
    "name": "example name",
    "author": " example author",
    "category": "example category",
    "img_link": "example.com/dist/img/junjo_cover.png"
    "manga_link": "example.com/junjo.html"
    },
]
```

Now i need link this json file to my card grid!

***How I can do this? Jquery, Ajax? and How to?***

I pick an example from the web [example card grib 4 col](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhH1F.png)

Comment: There are a multitude of things you can do here. I recommend you use JavaScript to render it to the HTML on load, using AJAX/jQuery to grab the data.

Comment: You can also use Javascript Arrays to help.  Pure Javascript is much faster than a javascript library.  Here is an example[Javascript Array](https://fiddle.jshell.net/NitroXAce/d1qro5g3/18/).

Comment: I don't think pure javascript array is better then json database! Because i have a lote of mangas on my json file! And i need recovery this data not only for my grid but for many pages!

Comment: You may want to get a look at Angular. A bit more work to get into, but it would make the above request very easy to implement.

Comment: @GarethCompton, sorry, but your example is not very good. 3 Arrays, unlinked attributes, Objects make much more sense here. JSON is **not** a library but a way of describing objects. Sure additional libraries can add overhead be it payload or speed and aren't required in this instance.

Comment: Good to know JSON isn't a library script.  And the arrays are simply adding different value to the for loop template below.  It was merely an example. :)

Comment: "How I can do this? Jquery, Ajax? and How to?" — You're already using PHP … so why not use PHP?

Comment: @Quetin Why not PHP? Becaus i'm using another Framework like Jekyll with a static page system! I know I know PHP can run this natively! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update

> *"I can use an external json file? @zer00ne"* – RITER

Indeed, there many ways to do so. I have an update of this demo using `$.getJSON()` and an external JSON file `data.json`. Remember that Same Origin Policy applies. Please review: **[Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/5DifQJsODR44oBpVcvax/)**. Although the demo cannot function fully as a Stack Snippet, one is posted as Demo 2 in accordance to site policy.

---

The object's keys didn't match what was in the HTML example so I adjusted accordingly. This particular JSON needed no parsing so as it is provided here's the breakdown:

```
[ //.................................................1st level is an array 
    { //.............................................2nd level is an object
    "name": "example name", //.......................Begin key:value pairs
    "author": " example author",
    "category": "example category",
    "img_link": "example.com/dist/img/junjo_cover.png"
    "manga_link": "example.com/junjo.html"//..........End key:value pairs
    },
]
```

Assign this object a variable and I changed the content to something less generic.

```
var manga = [{
  "name": "Cowboy Bebop: Shooting Star Volume One",
  "author": "Cain Kuga",
  "category": "Neo-noir, space Western",
  "img_link": "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51R00EADHML._SY291_BO1,204,203,200_QL40_.jpg",
  "manga_link": "https://web.archive.org/web/20030405062538/http://www.tokyopop.com/dbpage.php?page=product&productid=1620"
}];
```

The first level is an array:

```
manga[0]
```

The second level is an object:

```
manga[0].
```

To find the value of the category key:

```
manga[0].category
// "Neo-noir, space Western"
```

The HTML was input as a [**Template Literal**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which is a literal string on steroids. If we used a literal string we would concate the key values like so:

```
'<p class="card-text">'+ manga[0].category +'</p>'
```

Using a template literal we interpolate the key value:

```
 `<p class="card-text">${manga[0].category}</p>`
```

To render the template literal into HTML we can use `innerHTML` or something far superior [**`insertAdjacentHTML()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML), It's `innerHTML` on steroids.

### Demo 1

```js
var manga = [{
  "name": "Cowboy Bebop: Shooting Star Volume One",
  "author": "Cain Kuga",
  "category": " Neo-noir, space Western",
  "img_link": "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51R00EADHML._SY291_BO1,204,203,200_QL40_.jpg",
  "manga_link": "https://web.archive.org/web/20030405062538/http://www.tokyopop.com/dbpage.php?page=product&productid=1620"
}];

var HTML = `<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
      <div class="card h-100">
        <a href="${manga[0].manga_link}"><img class="card-img-top" src="${manga[0].img_link}"></a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">
            <a href="#">${manga[0].name}</a>
          </h4>
          <p class="card-text">${manga[0].category}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>`;

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', HTML);
```

```html
<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
```

### Demo 2

**Not functional it is posted in accordance to site policy. See this functional [**Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/5DifQJsODR44oBpVcvax/)** instead.**

```js
$.getJSON("data.json", function(manga) {



  var HTML = `<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
      <div class="card h-100">
        <a href="${manga[0].manga_link}">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="${manga[0].img_link}">
        </a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">
            <a href="#">${manga[0].name}</a>
          </h4>
          <p class="card-text">${manga[0].category}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>`;

  document.getElementById('dock').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', HTML);

});
```

```css
/* Imagine this as data.json file 

[{
 "name": "Cowboy Bebop: Shooting Star Volume One",
 "author": "Cain Kuga",
 "category": "Neo-noir, space Western",
 "img_link": "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51R00EADHML._SY291_BO1,204,203,200_QL40_.jpg",
 "manga_link": "https://web.archive.org/web/20030405062538/http://www.tokyopop.com/dbpage.php?page=product&productid=1620"
}]

*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<body>




  <section id='dock'></section>




  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
  <script src='script.js'></script>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I can use an external json file? @zer00ne

Comment: Yes, sir, see update.